# Caching Map Tiles Leads to Google Logo Showing Up on Every Tile. Any Way around this?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am part of a Solutions Engineering team giving product demonstrations of our software. We are currently trying to bring a stylized map, using mapstyle.withgoogle, into our application with no labels or landmarks to comply with our customer's request, so that we can use their network model without giving away who they are or where they are based. We have purchased an API key so that we can use this service. However, when we try to load the map tiles into our application, the Google Logo and copyright information gets slapped on every tile, making it very cluttered and unusable for our purposes. We cache the tiles locally so that we don't have to download the images every time we use the program, and I am wondering if this may be part of the issue, and whether or not there is a way around this.

This is the url being used:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key={k}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zHRy.png)&center={x},{y}&zoom={z}&format=png&maptype=roadmap&style=element:labels%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:administrative%7Celement:geometry%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:administrative.land_parcel%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:administrative.neighborhood%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:poi%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:road%7Celement:labels.icon%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:transit%7Cvisibility:off&size=256x256

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Downloading static maps images and stitching them later is against of the Google Maps Platform Terms of Services.

Have a look at paragraph 3.2.4 (a) in the Restrictions Against Misusing the Services section. It reads

> (a)  ***No Scraping***.  Customer will not extract, export, **scrape, or cache Google Maps Content for use outside the Services**. For example, Customer will not:(i) pre-fetch, index, store, reshare, or rehost Google Maps Content outside the services; (ii) bulk download geocodes; (iii) copy business names, addresses, or user reviews; or (iv) use Google Maps Content with text-to-speech services. Caching is permitted for certain Services as described in the Maps Service Specific Terms.

source: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license

This is a reason why Google puts logo and copyright in each static maps image.